# How can I use "redirect_to" removing requested subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

If I access to **http://walmart.example-site.com**
it redirects me to **http://walmart.example-site.com/communities/walmart**

But I want it to redirect to **http://example-site.com/communities/walmart**

How can I fix?

My codes are.

**routes.rb**

```
constraints(:subdomain => /.+/) do 
    root :to => 'communities#subdomain_redirect' 
end
```

**communities_controller.rb**

```
def subdomain_redirect
    @community = Community.find_by_community_name(request.subdomain)
    redirect_to @community
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match "/stories/:name" => redirect {|params| "/posts/#{params[:name].pluralize}" }
match "/stories" => redirect {|p, req| "/posts/#{req.subdomain}" }
```

is this something you need?? Try to refer to the official routing guide under secion 3.12 Redirection.

Comment: This is not. Sorry about my poor knowledge.

Comment: is that your purpose to set the root to subdomain to your root?

Comment: all I want that is removing subdomain when it redirects. That's it

Comment: then just do root :to => 'communities#subdomain_redirect', no nid constraint.

Comment: besides, for your subdomain_redirect in communities_controller, you have to get add a routes for it in your route too. example :
  get "communities/subdomain_redirect",:to => 'communities#subdomain_redirect', as: 'subdomain_redirect' ,is that what you need?

Comment: Please read my question again. It's already redirecting fine. But subdomain stays. I wanna remove this subdomain.

Comment: i think tis shld hlp u..http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 & http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains

Comment: <%= link_to "LINK", root_url(:subdomain => false) %>